# How to switch HiDPI application resolution without restarting them

Tags: xorg, gnome, monitors, resolution, application

I am running GNOME 3.26 with GDM on X.org. I have an external monitor at work and I am running my Laptop (Dell XPS 9550) and the monitor in about the same resolution (regarding dpi; both around ~1900x1200 px).

When I unplug the monitor my laptop switches to a much higher resolution: 3200x1800 px. Most apps are working fine (Nautilus, Firefox, Chrome, GNOME apps, ...), but some especially HiDPI aware apps like PHPStorm, Rambox, Typora (Java and Electron apps) show a much too small font and icon size.

The annoying thing is, I have to restart these applications to make them aware of the new resolution. Is there a way to trigger this behavior without restarting the applications?

*I know that I could run the laptop in standalone mode in the same resolution as when I have the external monitor plugged in, but I'd like to use the higher resolution, the above setup is actually already a workaround for the same problem, when running two displays with highly different dpi.*

Comment: How about restarting the shell via alt+f2 > r > enter ?

Comment: Sadly, this does not change the app resolution.

Comment: So, just to be clear, when your laptop switches to `WQXGA+` the gnome/gtk applications rescale while the java ones don't ? In that case the native apps are notified (maybe via dbus) and instantly change dpi while non-native ones don't communicate with the system and ignore the changes in resolution after they've been started. If so you're probably out of luck...

Comment: Yes, when the resolution is switched to `WQXGA+` the gnome/gtk apps switch their resolution. Sometimes it looks like they need like a few 10ths of a second to do so, but yes they get notified by "something".